# php web application architecture

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am building an internal invoicing platform (PHP and SQL)which would mostly interact to the database to read/write data. So the idea is to get some data from the databse and assign it to a particular tab. I have ~ 10 tabs and x amount of data to be read, which is growing on a constant pace. To limit the calls to database and improve the speed I am thinking of:
1. Have one call to the database
2. Create the buckets and save them in session
3. When some cells are updated by the user on the webpage I would update that row in the db and would not make a call to create new session, but instead update the current session variables and reasign the buckets.
4. Only one person will be working on this platform.

Is this a reasonable approach in terms of design and performance? Also, if there would be more people working on this platform in the future it would "break down", so I am also open to multi-person design suggestions.

The reason I want to avoid calls to the database, is because first I call a database y table x and get back names of all the database names of interest (they are not known in advnace), then I loop through the first call results and at each iteration call the unknown database to get some values (min,max, count, etc.). Therefore it feels very slow.

Comment: This seems as a premature optimization attempt. There is a good chance that a straightforward approach to data operations will not cause any performance problems or the bottleneck will be in some other part of the application.
I would suggest starting with the most simple approach and start thinking about caching and optimizing database requests only after the base functionality has been put in place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just updated the question with the reason why I want to avoid database calls. Do you think this could become/ or alrady is a bottleneck?

Comment: It might or might not be a bottleneck. It all depends very much on quite a few factors such as data size, complexity of queries and aggregations, usage of column indexes, etc. 
I don't think, anyone can have a universal solution for such a vague problem description. I still suggest you try the most simple approach first and watch for the bottlenecks on the working solution. Then you will have more clarity as to what to optimize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.